# Error in running scheduled Job. Where to find error details

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to delete row in SQL database when a column value matches with current date.
I have created a scheduled job for deletion of data using SQL Server Management Studio. I have followed step as shown in [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De_GOwnTDjo) 
Here Type of script is T-SQL and command I have given is:

```
Delete from NewDB.dbo.Datetabel where Date=getDate();
COMMIT
```

I want to schedule this job on daily basis. But now for testing purpose I have given on hourly basis. But this job is failed.

Where will I get the details of Error. I am working on sql2008 r2

What should be reason for failure?
Edited:
Now job is getting success when code is  changed as:

```
BEGIN TRAN 
Delete from NewDB.dbo.Datetabel where Date=getDate();
COMMIT;
```

But Data is not deleted from the tabel.
What may be issue now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go to the job in SQL Server Management Studio and right click and select view history. Inside the history it will give you a log. Drill into that to see what's happened.

Comment: You are comiting transaction without beginning it. Try with BEGIN TRAN as a first line.

Comment: Thanks Preet and Ozren. It worked and gave success message with this. But now data is not deleted from the tabel. What might be the cause?

Comment: Do where Date BETWEEN DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE()) AND DATEADD(millisecond,-3,DATEADD(d,1,DATEADD(d,0,DATEDIFF(d,0,GETDATE())))

Comment: With code given by you I was getting some error. I have done some change and its working!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN 
Delete from NewDB.dbo.Datetabel 
WHERE convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 111) = convert(varchar(10), Date, 111)
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Ozren I have added "BEGIN TRAN" to remove error.
and Its working fine with code :

```
BEGIN TRAN 
Delete from NewDB.dbo.Datetabel where DATEDIFF(day, Date, GETDATE()) = 0
COMMIT;
```